# changing the page's scrollbar colours IE

Tags: asp.net, css, scrollbar

How to change the scrollbar of the page itself (not of a particular control). For example if you zoom in on a page in IE it will eventually add scrollbars. Those are the scrollbars that I wish to change the colour of.

This code:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .scrollBars {
            scrollbar-face-color:#003366;
            scrollbar-highlight-color:gray;        
            scrollbar-shadow-color:gray;
            scrollbar-arrow-color:white;
            scrollbar-track-color:black;
        }
    </style>
```

works just fine if added to a listbox for example:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbTeams" SelectionMode="Single" Rows="5" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" Width="320" Font-Size="Larger" CssClass="scrollBars">
```

but not on the whole page for example.

Is that even possible for IE10?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the CSS:

```
body{
    scrollbar-base-color: #1C1C2B;
    scrollbar-face-color: #4C4C5E;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #1C1C2B;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #1C1C2B;
    scrollbar-track-color: #1C1C2B;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #4C4C5E;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #1C1C2B;
    scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #000;
}
```

Replacing the colors as you see fit. For reference [see here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design/). That said I'd generally shun scrollbar styling as its implemented differently across browsers, and not really at all in Firefox.

Comment: Only need to worry about IE, so other browsers are a non-issue. Will try that and see. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you're golden :)

Comment: Ok that doesn't seem to work. I had already tried adding class="scrollbars" to my body before and still nothing. Any idea why?